# AppEngine Java SDK 1.8.5 cannot be configured in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying out google-eclipse-plugin to develop a web app and host it in appEngine.

I Installed the latest google-plugin from https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3. Installation was successful but when I try creating a new google web-app, I can't go forward as it says AppEngine SDK is not properly configured.

It is pointed to: /home/eclipse_kepler/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.5/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.5

The error message it gives :Failed to intialize App Engine SDK at /home/eclipse_kepler/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.5/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.5

I tried manually configuring it by downloading the java-sdk from :
http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.5.zip

and giving the extracted location in eclipse. But still it gives the same error.
Is this a bug? Can I use a previous version of the java-sdk for my work?
Any help is appreciated